# Emacs: rename-save file?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible in Emacs to save a buffer to a different filename than the currently associated filename and to remove the file with the current filename?

For example, I'm editing file1.txt in a buffer. I would like to save this as file2.txt and want file1.txt to be deleted.

So just like "save as" in most programs, but with the extra removal.

I could write a function for this, but I'm wondering if something like this already exists in Emacs.

Comment: Yes, see this answer on stackoverflow.com:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/384346/133

Comment: Yes, that's the one I want! Tnx.